# Safari 6 border lingering after hover with border radius set

Tags: safari, rendering, css

I have a typical link on a page. On hover, the link receives a border color and border-radius. In Safari 6, I am noticing that when the mouse leaves the link there is a very faint border color left behind. If you hover again over the link, the border gets darker and darker in some cases, even though the border-color is not set. If border-radius is not set, the issue does not occur.

I cannot repeat the issue in Firefox or Chrome (for Mac). The simplest fix I found was to specify a solid or transparent border color for the base anchor style. Could this just be a Safari rendering bug?

Link for the rendering issue: http://jsfiddle.net/zafer/msnak/4/

Comment: Can't replicate this. Definitely not a problem with your screen/eyes?

Comment: I double-checked on someone else's Safari 6 and the issue still appears. The border does get very dark as you hover over repeatedly. It looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/BvY2p.png

Comment: Ah. So it wasn't just me. Noticed that since last week. Still haven't found a solution. It looks good at first, but when you roll over and out again and again, it gets just like your screenshot.

Comment: Forgot to mention that the background-clip trick doesn't fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the border-radius value equal to the padding on the anchor element and see if that doesn't help. I had the same problem in Safari 6 as well and that seemed to have fixed it.

So your CSS code would look something like this:

```
a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

a:hover {
  background: #004184;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just ran into same issue and found that using even values (2,4,6,..) as radius fixed it for me, like so:

```
a{
    color: white;
    padding-right: 9px;
    padding-left: 9px;
}
a:hover{
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

regardless of different padding values.

Answer (score 0):

The background-clip solution did fix the problem for me, check the details on https://stackoverflow.com/a/3447130/1200097 it is possible that your properties need to be reordered.