# Inner glow effect of button

Tags: css

I want to have inner glow effect of button when focused. I could achieve outline (outer) glow of button but I even want to have inner glow effect. Could anyone help?

Comment: Maybe have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572713/css3-gradients-to-reproduce-an-inner-glow-effect-from-illustrator-with-border-r

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ysFVw/) showing this effect:

```
a {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 30px #00f;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 30px #00f;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 30px #00f;
}
```

---

**Edit:** in response to your comment: Here's a [**much sexier version**](http://jsfiddle.net/ysFVw/2/).

Comment: i get inner glow effect with this thanks for your help. as i already mentioned i need to have both inner glow and outer glow together.if i include " -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 30px #00f;" along with -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 30px #00f;i can only see inner glow but not outer glow.

Comment: ha ha ha, is this sexier version? ;)

Comment: 2022 and "-moz-box-shadow" will give you a warning in FireFox 'Unknown property ‘-moz-box-shadow’.  Declaration dropped.' Seems Chrome doesn't mind though.

Answer (score 3):

use `box-shadow` `inset`:

```
.class{
  box-shadow:inset 2px 2px 2px 2px black;
}
```

http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/

Comment: +1, but you need the `-webkit-` and the `-moz-` duplicate styles.

Comment: yeah thats why provided the css3.info linke. CSS3 work is still under progress, yet the features like `box-shadow`, `border-radius` are implemented by major browsers (I don't consider IE as a browser)

Comment: Does anyone consider **that** thing a browser?