# Why chrome ignores border radius when a box inner shadow is set?

Tags: css, google-chrome

Take a look at this in both chrome and firefox: http://jsbin.com/imuxe3

As you see, it renders fine in firefox, but chrome literally ignores the `-webkit-border-radius` CSS rule when adding a `-webkit-box-shadow` with `inset` mode.

Can some one explain/get a solution for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in chrome. However you can use a workaround by defining a simple border: rule.

For more Details see this:
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=29427

Comment: I will +1 for the link when it's tomorrow (and I have votes again).

Answer (score 2):

[***I wondered about this recently, myself***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625058/#4625164).

Although, looking at [my button](http://jsfiddle.net/ysFVw/2/) in [Chrome dev](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/getting-involved/dev-channel) now, it's fixed.

So you must simply wait for the fix to the issue mentioned by @mightyuhu to be pushed to the stable version of Chrome.